# Jersey client does not return or read response from multiple class objects

Tags: java, web-services, jersey-client

My web service returning response from multiple entities. But when I am reading response by using response.readEntity(A.class). Note class A contains dependency of class B and class C. when I reading response from above statement I can only read contents of class A.

In postman everything is fine. Postman shows response which contains class A,B,C contents. But in jersey client I am not getting class B and C contents.

Can you please help me on this problem.

Following is my code for Java Pojo

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "TA_TESTPATTERN")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class TAPattern {
    private User User;
    private String TP_Type;
    private String Car;
    private String Category;
    private String Description;
    private TestCase TestCase;
    private String status;
    private String Customizable_Field;
    private RESULT_COLLECTION RESULT_COLLECTION;
    private String Id;
    private String xmlns;
    private String Variant;
    private String Code;
```

Here `RESULT_COLLECTION` is another class lets say `B`, and `RESULT_COLLECTON` again contains dependency of array of objects of class `RESULT`. Means `RESULT_COLLECTION` contains array of `RESULT` class array. So in my case class `TAPattern` is `A`, class `RESULT_COLLECTION` is `B` and class `RESULT` is `C`. And Test case is say `D`.

Following is my jersey client code:

```
Response response = invocationBuilder.header("Content-Type", "application/xml")
        .post(Entity.entity(vstpattern, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML));
return response.readEntity(TAPattern.class);
```

Following are POJO classes for `RESULT_COLLECTION`, `RESULT` and Test Case:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "RESULT_COLLECTION")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class RESULT_COLLECTION {
    private Result[] Result;
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "Result")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Result {
    private String Method;
    private String Href;
    private String Rel;
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "TestCase")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class TestCase {
    private String Method;
    private String Href;
    private String Rel;
}
```

Following is my jersey client code:

```
ConfigPropertyHandler configPropertyHandler = ConfigPropertyHandler.getInstance();
        ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
        HttpAuthenticationFeature feature = HttpAuthenticationFeature.basic(configPropertyHandler.getTid(),
                configPropertyHandler.getPassword());
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(config);
        client.register(feature);

        WebTarget webTarget = client.target(configPropertyHandler.getVstUrl()).path(configPropertyHandler.getVstPath());
        Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);

        Response response = invocationBuilder.header("Content-Type", "application/xml")
                .post(Entity.entity(vstpattern, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML));
        //return 0;


        return response.readEntity(TAPattern.class);

    }
```

Following is xml POSTMAN request:

```
 <TA_TESTPATTERN xmlns="http://examples.com" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <Car>MyCar</Car>
        <Id>122</Id>
        <Code>myCode</Code>
        <Description> TA TEST</Description>
        <TP_Type>VF</TP_Type>
        <Category>0</Category>
        <Variant>0</Variant>
        <Customizable_Field> nda </Customizable_Field>
        <status>w</status>
        <RESULT_COLLECTION>
            <Result>
                <Href>http://examples.com</Href>
                <Method>GET</Method>
                <Rel>READ</Rel>
            </Result>
            <Result>
                <Href>http://examples.com</Href>
                <Method>GET</Method>
                <Rel>READ</Rel>
            </Result>
        </RESULT_COLLECTION>
        <TestCase>
            <Href>http://examples.com</Href>
            <Method>GET</Method>
            <Rel>READ</Rel>
        </TestCase>
        <User>
            <ID>f10711a</ID>
            <email>abc@external.com</email>
            <Name>abc</Name>
        </User>
    </TA_TESTPATTERN>
```

Following is my TA_Pattern

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "TA_TESTPATTERN")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class TAPattern {


    @XmlElement(name = "User")
    private User User;

    @XmlElement(name = "TP_Type")
    private String TP_Type;

    @XmlElement(name = "Car")
    private String Car;

    @XmlElement(name = "Category")
    private String Category;

    @XmlElement(name = "Description")
    private String Description;

    @XmlElement(name = "TestCase")
    private TestCase TestCase;

    @XmlElement(name = "status")
    private String status;

    @XmlElement(name = "Customizable_Field")
    private String Customizable_Field;

    @XmlElement(name = "RESULT_COLLECTION") RESULT_COLLECTION RESULT_COLLECTION;

    @XmlElement(name = "Id")
    private String Id;

    @XmlElement(name = "xmlns")
    private String xmlns;

    @XmlElement(name = "Variant")
    private String Variant;

    @XmlElement(name = "Code")
    private String Code;
```

Following is POJO of VSTTAPattern

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "TA_TESTPATTERN")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class VSTTAPattern {


        private User User;

        private String TP_Type;

        private String Car;

        private String Category;

        private String Description;

        private TestCase TestCase;

        private String status;

        private String Customizable_Field;

        private RESULT_COLLECTION RESULT_COLLECTION;

        private String Id;

        private String xmlns;

        private String Variant;

        private String Code;
```

Comment: Why don't you post the code for your Jersey client and the code for class A.

Comment: So RESULT_COLLECTION is null when you try to read it?

Comment: yes RESULT_COLLECTION, Test Case and User all this type of class and can not read from response.read(TAPattern.class)

Comment: If RESULT_COLLECTION is a List then you should add a list to your TAPattern , public List<RESULT_COLLECTION> resColl; Of course, you'll probably want to make the list private and add the corresponding getters and setters.

Comment: RESULT_COLLECTION has array of RESULT[] class.RESULT_COLLECTION is not list. And Test case and User has String type parameters. Even I cant read these String type parameters also.

Comment: Can I update other POJO class also (RESULT_COLLECTION, RESULT and Test Case)

Comment: Post also classes for RESULT_COLLECTION and RESULT

Comment: Only TAPattern should have a @XmlRootElement. I'll write some code when I find the time. I'd also just have a List<Result> inside TAPattern. This would make for a cleaner (and simpler) design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd strongly suggest to change your design by removing RESULT_COLLECTION completely and adding a List of Result objects to your TAPattern class.

```
class TAPattern{

...
@XmlElement
private List<Result> resultList;
}

public List<Result> getResultList(){
if(resultList==null)
    resultList = new ArrayList<Result>();

 return resultList;
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) 
class Result {
....
}
```

This should make for a much cleaner design. That said, I'm not sure how you generate an xml response on the server and perhaps there are some constrains that I'm not aware of.

UPDATE: The code below works for me.

```
ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();

        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(config);

        WebTarget target = client.target(UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost:8088/JerseyRest").build());   

        User u = new User();
        u.email = "xx@xx.com";
        u.ID = "sjdgzuauoj";
        u.Name = "user name";
        TestCase tc = new TestCase();
        tc.Href = "yyyy@hreg.com";
        tc.Method = "POST";
        tc.Rel = "link@link.com";

        Result[] rArr = new Result[]{ new Result(), new Result()};
        rArr[0].Href = "href@href.com";
        rArr[0].Method = "GET";
        rArr[0].Rel = "READ";

        rArr[1].Href = "href@href1.com";
        rArr[1].Method = "POST";
        rArr[1].Rel = "WRITE";
        RESULT_COLLECTION rCol = new RESULT_COLLECTION();

        rCol.Result = rArr;
        TAPattern req = new TAPattern();
        req.RESULT_COLLECTION = rCol;
        req.Car = "Volvo";
        req.Category = "0";
        req.Code = "1";
        req.Customizable_Field = "0";
        req.Description = "Test";
        req.status = "Y";
        req.Variant = "0";
        req.TestCase = tc;
        req.User = u;
        //GenericType<List<TAPattern>> taList = new GenericType<List<TAPattern>>() {};
        try{

        // Get XML for application   
       Response res = target.path("rest").path("UserService").path("xxxr").request()
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).post(Entity.entity(req, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML),Response.class);

        TAPattern ta = (TAPattern)res.readEntity(TAPattern.class);
       for(Result r : ta.RESULT_COLLECTION.Result ){
           System.out.println("Href: "+r.Href);
           System.out.println("Rel: "+r.Rel);
           System.out.println("Mehod: "+r.Method);
       }

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
        return;
    }
```

You probably didn't populate the TAPattern object properly and as a result didn't get everything back.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts but I am just writing client. Web service implementation is not in my control. I have generated java POJO classes from xml and write jersey client only. In this case I am not updating or change code for web service implementation. Can you suggest any alternate way. Aprt from RESULT_COLLECTION, I am unable to read "Test case" and "User" data also. What is your comment on this issue?

Comment: Post everything and I'll try it when I find the time. Are you on Jersey 2 or earlier?

Comment: Thanks @dsp_user Already posted java POJO classes and client code and I am using jersey 1.9 version. Please let me know what else you want?

Comment: It might help if you have the server code as well. If not, at least post the request as you're using it from postman. I see that you're posting XML as payload.

Comment: Can you notice xml for POST request which I was uploaded recently?

Comment: Just to be clear. The XML you posted is what you sent to the server (request)? And then you return this same XML to the client?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply...request/response are same. You are right.

Comment: @dep_user can you see my comment?

Comment: Yes, I'll try your code but since it takes more than 10 minutes to that, you should give me some time.

Comment: No issue @dsp_user...thanks for your valuable time and efforts.

Comment: I haven't tried the Jersey client yet, but I've tried the JAXB part (unmarshalling the XML works just fine). Of course, Jersey will do this part automatically so no need to unmarshal manually. Well, it seems that at least your POJOs are fine.

Comment: Can you please tried Jersey client on my problem? I have stuck on that from pat one week and need to sort out this problem asap. Please look into this. I searched so many stuff on internet but did not get any solution.

Comment: I've tried it but no luck yet. I've also tried replacing Result[] with List<Result> but that didn't help either. It's strange because I have similar code (xml used as both a request and response), which works fine. I'm going to try some other things, in the meanwhile I can only post what I've tried but like I said it's still not working. I have Jersey 2.2.7 on one laptop (the one I tried your code on) but I intend to try it on another laptop (because I think it's possible thatt there's some version differences between Jersey andJAXB implementations)

Comment: Appreciate your efforts for my problem. Please help me on this issue because web service is also new for me ...I do at my best but stuck on same thing from past few days

Comment: Do you got any solution?

Comment: Sorry, it's been a busy day so I haven't had the time to try anything. I'm interested in solving this though I can't promise anything (it will depend on my free time)

Comment: Yes sure I understand. I am requesting for help.

Comment: Hi @dsp_user please help me to sort this problem

Comment: thanks a lot ...i update my code in workspace ..but I have little confusion about in Postman which content/xml I pass in body?

Comment: please guide me to construct URL from your code. Or share your URL path which you used in POSTMAN I will configure accordingly

Comment: I haven't used Postman at all. Instead, I created a Jersey client and used this client to send xml to the server (and receive the response). You said that your response was fine when you used Postman but it didn't work when you used your jersey client. So, I think that your constructed XML was wrong (the xml was probably missing something)

Comment: Show me how you construct **vstpattern** because I think your **vstpattern** is missing missing something.

Comment: You mean xml or Java POJO?

Comment: I am new to web service technology so please tell me about my following steps: I create POJOs from xml file. then write Jersey client. But which url I need to configure for target and how this url configure in web.xml?

Comment: I mean POJOs. You don't have to create your POJO from an xml file, Jersey will automatically (using JAXB internally) convert your your POJO to an xml representation. When you specify either MediaType.APPLICATION_XML or application/xml it's a signal to Jersey to convert to your Java classes / objects to xml. See my Jersey client code, it's all it takes.

Comment: If you need to populate your POJOs form an xml file (and not manually like I did above), then use JAXB. If you don't know how to do that, I can post a little code snippet.

Comment: If I write Jersey client(code which you update above) and POJOs then..this code runs correctly? Is it produce right output?

Comment: xml which I shared above for "TA_TESTPATTERN" gives me bad request error

Comment: How do you use that xml? Like I already said, the problem is probably in your *vstpattern* object but you haven't posted that part of the code. I think that you didn't  properly populate *vstpattern* and hence received a bad request error.

Comment: I have posted Vsttapattern POJO class is anything need to change?